# open dialog to download pdf

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a gridview in which I have provided an option for the user to download the pdf files. When they click on the pdf icon sometimes it open the pdf file in a new tab and sometimes it starts downloading. How can i make it download always?

Comment: It depends; you need to show us some code on how you are defining or retrieving the PDFs in the grid before we can provide answers.

Comment: on the click of the pdf icon i am opening the file using javascript:window.open('src');return false;

Answer (score 3):

You need to add a button (image button, linknbutton or button) and handle the RowCommand event of GridView. In RowCommand handler you may write code to download a file.

You may use `Response` object's method.

```
string filepath=MapPath("~/files/file.pdf");
byte []bytes=System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filepath);

Response.Clear();
Response.ClearHeaders();
Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", bytes.Length.ToString());
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=file.pdf");
Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
Response.Flush();
Response.End();
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to always force a download you need to add the Content-Disposition header as AVD showed; however, I find this totally unnecessary; I think it would suffice to have the link to the PDF open in a new window. In other words, have `target="_blank"` defined. Example:

```
<a href="file.pdf" target="_blank">invoice</a>
```

Then, is up to the user whether he wants to save the file locally or just see it on the screen. I think the important thing is that this won't interfere with the current page the user is looking at.